# How to fix normal map texture to show properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture-mapping

My normal map texture does not work on imported objects (left), but works on objects created in Unity (right).

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure your imported objects have tangent, binormal, and a second uv channel if your shader expects them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your imported object has UV Map. If it has UV map it should work like the unity native object, there is no special  thing to do in order to make it work.

Here is a tutorial explaining how to do it with the free 3D software BLENDER -> http://sophiehoulden.com/tutorials/blender/unwrapTut.html

Comment: There is also youtube tutorial for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k